# nearest point search with weighted distances using boost rtree

Tags: c++, nearest-neighbor, boost-geometry

I am storing points (xi,yi) in a boost rtree and then query for a point (xq,yq), which point (xi,yi) is the nearest:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

int main() {
    typedef bg::model::point<int, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<point, false, false> polygon; // ccw, open polygon
    typedef std::pair<point, int> value;

    const int M = 4000 * 4000;
    const int N = M / 10000;

    bgi::rtree< value, bgi::rstar<16, 4> > rtree;
    for (int in = 0; in < N; in++)
    {
       point p(rand(), rand());
       rtree.insert(value(p, in));
    }   
    for (int im = 0; im < M; im++)
    {
       point p(rand(), rand());
       std::vector<value> vp;
       int found = rtree.query(bgi::nearest(p, 1), std::back_inserter(vp));
    }
 }
```

Now I want to use a weighted distance metric, where each point (xi,yi) has a weight assigned, which modifies the distance (e.g. by multiplying the euclidian distance with the weight). I am wondering if this is possible using boost, or is there another toolbox, which can accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you're no longer focusing on geometry, but rather a general graph algorithm. I'd consider using a graph library (Boost Graph is such a toolbox)

Comment: Well, there is something like a weighted voronoi diagram. Since I dont need the diagram, I try to implement it using the spatial index.

Comment: Do you weights have some properties (say they don't vary too much between nearby points), or are they arbitrary?

Comment: @MiB_Coder The one library that I know "does" voronoi in boost is Boost Polygon (not Boost Geometry). I'm not sure it has much/any query capability.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Well they are certainly not arbitrary, but I can not quanitfy right now, how much variation will be required.

Comment: You mention a multiplicative weight as an example. Do you need specifically this type of weight, or is any kind of bias ok? For instance, adding something to squared distances maybe be easier to handle.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Actually I don't have a specific requirement. All I need to do is to somehow tweak the "circle of influence" of each point.

Comment: Then I think adding a weight to the squared distance is easier. You could use a Regular_triangulation_2 from CGAL (if you can lookup many points at once, maybe spatial sort them first and use the location of the previous point as hint for the next call to locate; if you cannot, use the hierarchy). I remember seeing an undocumented kd-tree for weighted points in  https://github.com/grey-narn/hera/tree/master/wasserstein/include/dnn . There are probably other options...

Comment: A simple trick may be to transform coordinates before inserting them into the index. If 'y' should be twice as expensive as 'x', simply multiply all y-coordinates by 2 before inserting them. Afterwards you can use a normal euclidean query, just don't forget to transform your query point.